# Split the Paragraph using "." in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I wanted to split the paragraph in node using full stop but again there are some exceptions that I need to check before splitting it. For Ex I wanted to split the following paragraph using "." but it should not affect the statements which contain website name or email Id or statements that are in parenthesis ().

```
 My Country is best country in the world.My country name is India. This country belongs to several states.each state has different users which are using website named www.google.com or www.facebook.com. My state named Maharashtra uses email Id starting with dummy@gmail.com.
```

Can anybody please help me on that ?

Comment: I need a dog, it must not bark nor bite, its left eye must be orange, and the right eye must be green ... What've I tried? Well, I've a can of green paint.

Comment: The inconsistent use of starting a new sentence with a capital letter, is that intentional?

Comment: No it is not intentional. Just for dummy paragraph I have added like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegExp

`var newContent = content.replace(​/([.?!])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|");`

Comment: Its not working. Can you please suggest me any other thing ?